# Text from 1 form to another form in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

I'm using [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms). I have 2 forms which contain a `TextBox` and a `Button` in each form. My goal is to get the content from the `TextBox` on `form1` to the TextBox on `form2` on a click of a button. I also want to close form1 and only show `form2` with the content that was typed in the TextBox on `form1`.

This is what I have so far. The problem with my code is the content doesn't show in `form2`.

```
this.Hide();

Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.ShowDialog();

f2.textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text;           

this.Close();
//close form1
```

Comment: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/thiagu304/passdata05172006234318PM/passdata.aspx

Comment: Your assignment is *after* the ShowDialog() call.  So only runs after the dialog is closed.  Too late.  Just move it before the call.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the code you provided is from your button click event. It can be simply modified as follows to get what you need.

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text;  
f2.Show();

this.Close();
```

However if your Form1 is the main form, i.e. it is loaded from Program.cs. Your application will just exit after `this.Close()`

I also advise that you don't make Form2's textBox1. Keep the property `private` and create a function to modify its value, for example: Create this function in Form2

```
public void SetTextBox1Text(string text)
{
    textBox1.Text = text;
}
```

And your Form1 button click event:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2();
f2.SetTextBox1Text(textBox1.Text);  
f2.Show();

this.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

First in your Form2.cs add a property to expose your private textBox1 as a good practice.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    //this is a property
    public string TextBox1
    {
        get { return textBox1.Text; }
        set { textBox1.Text = value; }
    }
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Next, in your Form1.cs, assign the value of textBox1 to Form2 first before showing the dialog.

```cs
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        //assign the value first before showing the dialog
        f2.TextBox1 = textBox1.Text;
        f2.ShowDialog();

        this.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`ShowDialog()` displays a modal window of `Form2` which means you cannot go to the parent form which is `Form1`

```
f2.textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text;           
this.Close();
```

The above two lines are written after `f2.ShowDialog();` which will execute only when `Form2` is closed. Hence you are not getting any text in the `TextBox` in `Form2`.

And coming to the part where you are sending the `Form1` `TextBox` value to `Form2`, the shortest and easiest way is to pass the `Form1` `TextBox` value as string to the constructor of `Form2`.

Following is the code which

Form1 Button Click:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    Form2 f2 = new Form2(textBox1.Text);
    f2.ShowDialog();           
}
```

Form 2 constructor:

```
public Form2(string Text)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox1.Text = Text;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

The problem lies here:

```
f2.ShowDialog();
```

The method `ShowDialog()` is a blocking call. The code you have after this will simply not be executed until `f2` is closed. Try replacing it with `Show()`.

Edit: as pointed out by @Abhishek, using `Show()` doesn't solve the problem since you want to close the first form after the second one is done. The problem is still the same though, `ShowDialog()` will wait there for a DialogResult and therefor will not execute the next statement. Consider setting the textbox content before showing the form.

Comment: Did you try before you posted an answer?

Comment: @Abhishek I did test this, and it's obvious since `ShowDialog()` returns a DialogResult. Maybe the term `blocking call` wasn't the most precise one, but OP's `f2.textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text` will not be executed until the `f2` form is closed.

Comment: Ya. So when you replace `f2.ShowDialog();` with `f2.Show();`, what happens according to the code sequence is the `TextBox` value is set and then the applications closes when `this.Close()` is executed, which is not the desired output.

Comment: Now of course this is a concern, but it is not the question. OP wanted to know why the textbox wasn't getting filled, and my answer fits his question properly I think

Comment: You have pointed out the problem rightly. But, with all due respect, using `Show()` does not help with the problem. This is what I am trying to point out. :)

Comment: @Abhishek, I made an edit clarifying a bit, hope this is clearer and more precise. Thanks for the feedback!